# Is there a general algorithm to flatten nested lhs cases in functional programming languages?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, types, functional-programming

Functional programming languages, like Haskell, allow users to define functions using an equational notation, where the left-hand side has several pattern arguments that can be matched, with arbitrary many nests. For example:

```
(fun (Ctr A A) (Foo (Tic X)) a b c d e) = a
(fun (Ctr A B) (Foo (Tac Y)) a b c d e) = b
(fun (Ctr B A) (Bar (Tic X)) a b c d e) = c
(fun (Ctr B B) (Bar (Tac Y)) a b c d e) = d
(fun x         y             a b c d e) = (df x y a b c d e)
```

Suppose, though, that you wanted to compile that function to a language that didn't allow nested pattern matches. That is, you'd have to flatten these clauses into a series of functions that, grouped together, would be equivalent to `fun`. For example, in the case above, you could flatten it as follows:

```
(fun (Ctr x1 x2) (Foo x3) a b c d e) = (fun_0 x1 x2 x3 a b c d e)
(fun (Ctr x1 x2) (Bar x3) a b c d e) = (fun_1 x1 x2 x3 a b c d e)
(fun x           y        a b c d e) = (df x y a b c d e)

(fun_0 A A (Tic x0) a b c d e) = (fun_0_0 x0 a b c d e)
(fun_0 A B (Tac x0) a b c d e) = (fun_0_1 x0 a b c d e)
(fun_0 x y z        a b c d e) = (df (Ctr x y) (Foo z) a b c d e)

(fun_1 B A (Tic x0) a b c d e) = (fun_1_0 x0 a b c d e)
(fun_1 B B (Tac x0) a b c d e) = (fun_1_1 x0 a b c d e)
(fun_1 x y z        a b c d e) = (df (Ctr x y) (Bar z) a b c d e)

(fun_0_0 X a b c d e) = a
(fun_0_0 x a b c d e) = (df (Ctr A A) (Foo (Tic x)) a b c d e)
(fun_0_1 Y a b c d e) = b
(fun_0_1 x a b c d e) = (df (Ctr A B) (Foo (Tac x)) a b c d e)
(fun_1_0 X a b c d e) = c
(fun_1_0 x a b c d e) = (df (Ctr B A) (Bar (Tic x)) a b c d e)
(fun_1_1 Y a b c d e) = d
(fun_1_1 x a b c d e) = (df (Ctr B B) (Bar (Tac x)) a b c d e)
```

My question is: is there a general algorithm that flattens nested lhs pattern matches into un-nested clauses, with the lowest amount of clauses possible?

Comment: I would think that in general the approach is not to create a "series of functions", where each function has multiple definitions, but rather at first the group of definitions is merged into a single function definition with a `match` expression. Then you can easily transform linear patterns into nested `match` expressions

Comment: @Bergi the question is, per requirement, how to convert a series of equations with nested matches into an equivalent series of equations without nested matches. (Specifically, that is meant to compile functional languages to HVM (https://github.com/kindelia/hvm), which natively supports equations with parallel non-nested left-hand side matches, so converting to serial `match` expressions would greatly inhibit performance.)

Answer (score 6):

Chapter 4 of Simon PJ's "The Implementation of Functional Programming Languages" is dedicated to this topic. See here for a pdf: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1987/01/slpj-book-1987-small.pdf

The chapter is coauthored by Phil Wadler, one of the designers of Haskell.

While this book uses a pre-Haskell style syntax, the ideas carry over. When GADTs, pattern-match completeness etc are involved, you'll need to look at newer papers; but the basic idea/algorithms remain the same.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems like the paper suggests translating the equational notation into a sequence of pattern-matching lambdas, which may succeed or fail. So, basically, this would be the same as compiling all the lines into a single flat λ-expression. But it isn't obvious to me how, once that is done, we could go back and generate the flattened equations I've shown on the thread. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MaiaVictor You can always give the lambdas a name and move their definitions out of line, can't you? What else is required for the form you're after?

Comment: But then how would you get to, say, `(fun_1 B A (Tic x0) a b c d e) = (fun_1_0 x0 a b c d e)`? That is doing 3 matches in a single equation, so you'd end up with more equations than needed. If I understand correctly, Simon's proposal would end up with each equation doing just 1 match, which may impact performance (note I'm compiling to run, not elaborating to type-check!). Great answer though, and very good find.

Comment: (I think starting from Simon's algorithm and then merging separate/compatible equations into one might provide the answer I need.)